# Change title bar color

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to change the backcolor and forecolor of the title bar in VB.NET
I tried this code

```
Me.Style.TitleBar.BackColor = Color.Black
Me.Style.TitleBar.ForeColor = Color.White
```

but it gives this error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30456 'Style' is not a member of 'about'.

'about' is the form name

I'm using visual studio 2019

Comment: Take a read of of this question [Is there a way I can change the color of the title bar of my form? VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594511/is-there-a-way-i-can-change-the-color-of-the-title-bar-of-my-form-vb-net)

Comment: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can't natively change the color of the title bar in VB.NET unfortunately.  You would need to remove the title bar from your app and code in your own.  Unfortunately that would be hard to do if you wanted it to look like the default windows title bar since the style changes depending on the OS version and settings.